# Windows to Linux utf-8 file

Tags: windows, linux, utf-8, mojibake

I have a file UTF-8 encoding in windows, and when i use it under windows it shows everithing right, but when i copy the file in Linux, the Unicode characters are giberish. The file is plain textfile. How can i get this file to be readable in linux, or how can i copy it properly??

thanks in advance

Comment: Something is off. Show us what you see. If possible, some output from `od -c`.

Comment: this is part of the translationf files

$Tools = "Алатки"; $langDownloadFile = "Качиување на датотеката"; ins windows

and the result u can see here 
http://testor.subnet.at/ndokeos/index.php?language=macedonian

Comment: The question marks on that page are actual question marks. It's breaking earlier. Show the raw contents of the files.

Comment: in putty with less i get this
ºÐ°Ñ°Ð°?>; $langTooBig $
for more information: see languages.txt in the lang folder.
*/
$Tools = "ÐÐ»Ð°ÑÐºÐ¸"; $langDownloadFile = "ÐÐ°ÑÐ¸ÑÐ²Ð°ÑÐµ Ð½Ð° Ð´Ð°ÑÐ¾ÑÐµÐºÐ°ÑÐ?>; $langTooBig =$

but the link shows the files pretty nice

http://testor.subnet.at/ndokeos/main/lang/macedonian/work.inc

Comment: Have you got Apache and/or PHP set up to serve the proper character set? According to Firefox that's being served as Western ISO-8859-15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like an Apache/PHP issue

Are you running your strings through PHP's built-in htmlspecialchars method  (or similar)? If so, you may need to switch its encoding to UTF8

Instead of `htmlspecialchars($mytext)`, try using `htmlspecialchars($mytext, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')`

---

Note the following (my previous answer) is incorrect, as Michael Burr notes, UTF-8 doesn't need or use the BOM.

> If it's just the text, then there's a chance it's missing the Byte Order Mark (BOM), or is encoded with an incorrect BOM.
>
> If it's incorrect, the linux reader may be honouring it but your windows reader is ignoring it. Try re-opening your file in something like Notepad++ and resaving. Notepad++ has a bunch of options in the Format menu about saving UTF-8 files.

Comment: i did, and i tried all the linux options but still the same. apache doesent recognize it also. it shows me only ????????.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have transfered the file in binary mode. Also try iconv.

Comment: i did this and still the same result :(

Comment: Transferring in binary mode would just makes the line breaks CRLF instead of LF.  It wouldn't affect the multibyte UTF-8 characters.

Answer (score 0):

The file itself is fine. Something else in the pipe is screwing up the text before it gets sent to the browser. Echo the text at various points in the app to pinpoint which operation is breaking it.